# How to send data between route pages in flutter?

Tags: flutter

So i have two page, and im using this to navigate to the other page

`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('page-2');`

how do i pass the data object from page 1 and sent to page 2?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a good way to do this right now with named routes. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a topic that's still being discussed as @Linus Juhlin mentioned, actually it came up again last week in the [flutter google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/HlGpwzzMB00)

You can actually use [the `onGenerateRoute` property from `MaterialApp`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/main.dart#L141) to build the `Route`s yourself as shown in the [stocks demo app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/main.dart#L86-L110). This gets a bit tricky because you'll have to pass in a string representation of the data you need to pass to the next page [when pushing the route](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/stock_home.dart#L263).

You can also use a library called [Fluro](https://github.com/goposse/fluro#navigating) which hides some of that boilerplate code and you just have to define handler functions to handle each route.